# Display data on ASP.NET wep page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello guys I have solved the issue I had with data being displayed with a repeater and I have added a paging system. Now I have been searching for a method to create a cart system using the repeater I have created with the use of an add to cart button. Could anyone provide some hints and tips or even sample code of how to achieve this, here is my code below.

```
public partial class A4_Label : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindRepeater();
        }

    }

    public void BindRepeater()
    {
        SqlConnection Connstr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VictoriaWorksConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [dbo].[A4 Label].ProductName,[dbo].[A4 Label].ProductType, [dbo].[A4 Label].ProductDescription, [dbo].[A4 Label Info].Quantity, [dbo].[A4 Label Info].Price FROM [dbo].[A4 Label] ,[dbo].[A4 Label Info]  WHERE  [dbo].[A4 Label].ProductID = [dbo].[A4 Label Info].ProductID ",Connstr);

        if (Connstr.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            Connstr.Open();
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        pgitems.DataSource = dv;
        pgitems.AllowPaging = true;
        pgitems.PageSize = 15;
        pgitems.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber;

        if (pgitems.PageCount > 1)
        {
            rptPaging.Visible = true;
            ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < pgitems.PageCount; i++)
                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
            rptPaging.DataSource = pages;
            rptPaging.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            rptPaging.Visible = false;
        }
            A4Repeater.DataSource = pgitems;
            A4Repeater.DataBind();   
    }


    public int PageNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
            else
                return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
        }
     }


    protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
        BindRepeater();
    }
```

Comment: You have a problem here in that you've followed an article with code applicable to winforms (hence the `Console.WriteLine`). This is fine, and you've done well to get the data from the DB, but rendering it out is where the difference lies between windows and web. Research 'repeater and databinding for asp .net' and you'll have your answer. I doubt this question will be very well received on here to be honest.

Comment: You should start with just about *any* introductory tutorial on ASP.NET.

Comment: thanks DeeMac I will look into repeater and databinding as I want to do a shopping basket feature. this is why I am displaying product information on the web page.

Comment: @YasarMunir - walk before you can run, and I don't mean that in a patronising way at all. Make sure you break down your problems into small, manageable tasks and read a lot.

Comment: Better look for some more code you can USE from someone elses hard work

Comment: hey guys thanks for all your replies and DeeMac you were right I am able to display my data with a repeater as well as a paging system. so thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Console.WriteLine` in ASP.NET. ASP.NET is a technology framework built for the Web, not for the Console applications in the Windows.

What you wanted to use would be this

```
Response.Write(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} ", 
                             column[0], column[1],  column[2],  column[3],  column[4]));
```

This would write the content as a Response to the request sent to the server. I would definitely forward you to the [ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net) and there you can find the documentations about the ASP.NET too. You can write the very same result on the ASP.NET web page using many methods, which includes this method (`Response.Write`) and another method to call the View and generate the result and so on. Depends on how you run it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx

#### Why not to use `Response.Write()`

Technically, this method is available in ASP.NET to write the data. But this is not a good approach, example of this is just like `document.write()` from JavaScript, it adds the content and overwrite the other data. In ASP.NET it doesn't do the same, but it prepends the data to the top of the page, so like `Console.WriteLine` appends, this method prepends the data to the `body` element.

Instead of this, you can call the result from the Database. And after that you can write the data in the HTML body using Razor syntax like

```
<div>@A4_Data.Readrowdata</div>
```

It would provide you with the same result and would be inside the div that you want it to be.

Comment: While technically correct, it's at least worth noting that using `Response.Write` like this is an awful idea.  The output will look terrible and the developer would have no control over where it's placed on the page.

Comment: @David, exactly. But using `Response.Write` for an ajax call would be a good idea, to get only the related string. I would add this to my answer about the details of this. :)

Comment: You're likely going to confuse him if you say to use `Response.Write` in a regular page context. Instead, for a simple example you can just concatenate strings to a Label or Literal control.

Comment: hey guys thank you for your suggestions, what i want to do is display product information data on a web page as a list or table. I than want to allow the user to add the certain products to a shopping cart. what is the best possible method to acheive this will it be repeater and databinding?

Comment: @YasarMunir There's way too many possible ways for us to tell you the "best possible". You just need to pick a way and try to implement it, then come to us if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind your result to an Asp GridView and let the technology do the work for you?

http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/BindSqlDataReadertoGridView.htm

```
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What has Java to do with this?

Comment: Did you even click on the link and see what was posted before you down voted?  The answer shows how to bind a SqlDataReader to an Asp GridView on an aspx page.  It has nothing to do with Java, other than JAVA being in the URL.

Comment: I am sorry, but I never downvoted your answer brother. It is someone else who did so, I was sleeping all these 6 hours ! :P

Comment: NP Afzaal...it may have been the OP.  The link does show how to use server side ASP objects to display the data.  Looks like there is some feature creep from the OP though to not only display, but also implementing shopping cart functionality.

Comment: Yes, I have seem the link afterward, the code is for the `ASP` there. OP might get a chance to see the code on that page. :)

Comment: You have a few ways to code this.  My above server-side example, ASP.Net objects generate your HTML.  Post backs update the cart as user changes.  Another option is using JavaScript/Ajax to display the data/implement your cart.  You can also hybrid these two methods.  As mason said, there's no 'best way', it all depends on your requirements/skill level.  Google "Web Forms Shopping cart example" and implement in your app a solution you like.  (ASP.Net - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Online-Shopping-Cart-8cd04946 or AJAX - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8)